# Calling MATLAB from C++ dyld: Library not loaded error

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I'm trying to run the following example found at http://www.box.net/shared/xmazi14uv2.

But when I make and try to run the executable, I encounter the following error:

```
./demo
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libeng.dylib
```

I've had no success searching the web. I'm running MATLAB_R2014b on a MacBook Pro Air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use or even have access to a Mac, but I think you need to setup some environment variables when you run applications using the MATLAB Engine:

```
export PATH='/path/to/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin':$PATH

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='/path/to/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin/maci64:/path/to/MATLAB_R2014b.app/sys/os/maci64':$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: @kirikoumath so find the path to libeng.dylib and do it again

Comment: thank you so much. That worked, I just had a typo somewhere in my Makefile